# django rest framework json serializer

Tags: json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I want json response from Django rest framework,so I have Json Response like this:                                                                                                                                                                                                                       .

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "TitleEnglish": "Tiny Talents Program",
        "TitleArabic": "Tiny Talents Program",
        "DescriptionEnglish": "Timing: 8:00 am till 1:00 pm",
        "DescriptionArabic": "Timing: 8:00 am till 1:00 pm",
        "CategoryEnglish": "Art & Education ",
        "CategoryArabic": "Art & Education ",
        "Date": "2015-05-07",
        "Status": true,
        "Image": "--"
    }
]
```

but i need response like this:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "TitleEnglish": "Tiny Talents Program",
        "TitleArabic": "Tiny Talents Program",
        "DescriptionEnglish": "Timing: 8:00 am till 1:00 pm",
        "DescriptionArabic": "Timing: 8:00 am till 1:00 pm",
        "CategoryEnglish": "Art & Education ",
        "CategoryArabic": "Art & Education ",
        "Date": "2015-05-07",
        "Status": true,
        "Image": "--"
    }
       ]
}
```

My serializer code is :

```
class PromotionSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    CategoryEnglish  = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, source="Category.TitleEnglish")
    CategoryArabic  = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, source="Category.TitleArabic")
    class Meta:
        model = Promotion
        fields = ('id', 'TitleEnglish', 'TitleArabic', 'DescriptionEnglish', 'DescriptionArabic', 'CategoryEnglish','CategoryArabic', 'Date','Status','Image')
```

Comment: You need to create a custom renderer. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#custom-renderers I have never tried this, but I believe it fits your problem

Answer (score 8):

I solved my problem by changing in my Views:

I added a list method, my problem is solved:

```
def list(self, request):
    queryset = Promotion.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PromotionSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    serialized_data =  {'data': serializer_class.data}
    return Response(serialized_data)
```

Comment: Great! I was also working on the same and did by defining a  `list_serializer_class` in the `Meta` class in the serializers. Will update my previous ans.

Comment: That is an another option to solve the problem with less code and less of overriding! +1

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to override to_representation method

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    data = super(PromotionSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
    return {'data': data }
```

Comment: this is elegant!

Answer (score 2):

**I think you can do that by customizing the [`ListSerializer`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#listserializer) behavior which is used when creating serialized response for `list` requests.**

We can create a custom `PromotionListSerializer` which will be used when multiple instances are passed to serializer for serialization using `many=Tue` argument.

We override the `data` property in our `PromotionListSerializer` class to return our custom representation instead.

```
class PromotionListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):

    @property
    def data(self):
        # call the super() to get the default serialized data
        serialized_data =  super(PromotionListSerializer, self).data       
        custom_representation = {'data': serialized_data} # insert the above response in a dictionary
        return custom_representation
```

Then in your `PromotionSerializer`, specify this custom list serializer class in `Meta`. This custom list serializer class will be used then when serializing multiple instances.

```
class PromotionSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    CategoryEnglish  = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, source="Category.TitleEnglish")
    CategoryArabic  = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, source="Category.TitleArabic")
    class Meta:
        model = Promotion
        fields = ('id', 'TitleEnglish', 'TitleArabic', 'DescriptionEnglish', 'DescriptionArabic', 'CategoryEnglish','CategoryArabic', 'Date','Status','Image')

        # define the custome list serializer class to be used
        list_serializer_class = PromotionListSerializer
```

**Solution-2:**

Override the `list` method of the view and return custom representation instead of the default response which you have done as mentioned in [your ans.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31901492/4921103)

Extending the [OP's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3779350/muhammad-naeem-paracha) answer, this will provide support for paginated response also. This is the actual code in DRF and i have just returned the `custom_representation` instead of `serializer.data` at the end.

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
    page = self.paginate_queryset(instance)
    if page is not None:
        serializer = self.get_pagination_serializer(page)
    else:
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, many=True)
    serialized_data = serializer.data
    custom_representation = {'data': serialized_data}
    return Response(custom_representation)
```

Comment: still have problem
`[
   {
    "data":  {
               "id": 1,
               "TitleEnglish": "Tiny Talents Program",
               "TitleArabic": "Tiny Talents Program",
               "DescriptionEnglish": "Timing: 8:00 am till 1:00 pm",
               "DescriptionArabic": "Timing: 8:00 am till 1:00 pm",
               "CategoryEnglish": "Art & Education ",
               "CategoryArabic": "Art & Education ",
               "Date": "2015-05-07",
               "Status": true,
               "Image": "--"
             }
    }
]`

Comment: I want to remove starting array and start with dictionary and then array of data see in my question format. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Updated the ans. Actually, just overriding the `to_representation` won't work in case of `list` request i.e. when multiple instances are being serialized. DRF uses a `ReturnList` class in `.data` property after `to_represention` has been called which again gave me a list. I could solve the problem by creating a Custom list serializer class and overriding the `data` property so that it returns my custom representation.

Comment: Your method as given in the ans is also correct to solve the problem. I have slightly extended your solution. Please check. :)

Comment: Thank You, it will also solve my problem, but i already solve it :)

Comment: Thats good! Also don't forget to accept your answer if that worked for you as it might help others having the same problem. :)